# How to get the size of the intersecting part in a circle in Java

Tags: java, math, floating-point, geometry

I need the size of the black part of this image:
[image]

I've done some research about how to find it in normal math, and I was pointed to this website: [Website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html%20%22Wolfram.com)

The final answer on getting it was 
[image: pict]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/Circle-CircleIntersection/Inline41.gif))</sub>

where r is the radius of the first circle, R the radius of the second circle, and d the distance between the two centers.

The code I tried to use to get the size of this was the following:

```
float r = getRadius1();
float R = e.getRadius1();
float deltaX = Math.abs((getX()  + getRadius()) - (e.getX() + e.getRadius()));
float deltaY =  Math.abs((getY()  + getRadius()) - (e.getY() + e.getRadius()));
float d = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));

float part, part2, part3;
//Chopping it in parts, because it's easier.

part = (float) (Math.pow(r,2) * Math.acos(
      Math.toRadians((Math.pow(d, 2) + Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(R, 2))/(2*d*r))));

part2 = (float) (Math.pow(R,2) * Math.acos(
      Math.toRadians((Math.pow(d, 2) + Math.pow(R, 2) - Math.pow(r, 2))/(2*d*R))));

part3 = (float) (0.5 * Math.sqrt((-d + r + R) * (d+r-R) * (d-r+R) * (d+r+R)));

float res = part + part2 - part3; 

Main.log(res + "       " + part + " " + part2 + " " + part3+ "       "
         + r + " " + R  + " " + d);
//logs the data and System.out's it
```

I did some testing, and the output was this:

```
1345.9663       621.6233 971.1231 246.78008       20.0 25.0 43.528286
```

So that indicates that the size of the overlapping part was bigger than the circle itself (which is `r^2 * PI`).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I would use `double` instead of `float` as it will have less representation error, but not enough to explain yours. ;)

Comment: Can you show us the formula for deltaX and Y because they don't look right?  What is the difference between getRadius() and getRadius1() ?

Comment: Why do you have getRadius1() and e.getRadius1()? Are you forgetting to get the radius of r?

Comment: Just as a side note: try caching the `Math.pow(x, 2)` operations (where x is r, R or d) as it makes things easier to read and increases performance (those values are caluclated multiple times and they don't change during the calculation, do they? :) ).

Comment: Just a thought: are you sure the calculated parameter for `Math.acos()` is in degrees rather than radians? If not, you might want to skip that `Math.toRadians(...)` conversion (if they are already expressed in radians).

Comment: Exemplary question. Hope you don't mind my reformat, just a bit more whitespace and got rid of the horizontal scrollbar in the code block. Note that with Markdown you don't need to supply `<br/>` to get linebreaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess (as stated in my comment): try removing the `Math.toRadians(...)` conversion.

Since there are no degrees involved in the formula but rather radii, I assume the parameter to *cos<sup>-1</sup>(...)* is already a value in radians.

If I remove the conversion and run your code, I get the following overlap area size: `11.163887023925781`  which seems plausible since the length of the overlap segment on the line between the two centers is `20 + 25 - 43.5 = 1.5` (approximated)

*Edit*:

If I set the distance to 5 (the smaller circle is completely contained in the bigger one but touches its edge) I get the overlap area size `1256.63` which is exactly the area of the smaller circle (20<sup>2</sup> * Π). The calculation doesn't seem to work if the distance is smaller than the difference of the radii (i.e. in your case smaller than 5), but that might just be a problem of numerical representation (the normal datatypes might not be able to represent some of the intermediate results).

Comment: `Math.acos(Math.toRadians(...))` is definitely wrong, as the argument to `Math.acos()` is not an angle. The argument to `Math.acos()` should be a value between -1 and 1, and will return a value in radians.

Comment: Hi, How to get the intersecting points ? Please suggest the solution in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177728/how-to-get-the-intersecting-points-from-shape-in-elasticsearch